# Using md5 at userPassword (OpenLDAP)

Tags: ssh, md5, openldap

I'm using LDAP for ssh autorithation.

userPassword with {crypt} working fine, but {md5} doesn't work.

```
ldapmodify -Vv -D "cn=Manager,dc=*,dc=*" -W -f *.ldif
```

*.ldif:

```
dn: uid=*,ou=People,dc=*,dc=*
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: {CRYPT}eGUw6pD1aAClQ
```

*.ldif:

```
dn: uid=*,ou=People,dc=*,dc=*
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: {MD5}ICy5YqxZB1uWSwcVLSNLcA==
```

Standart configuration:
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Centralized_authentication_using_OpenLDAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using ssha:

```
slappasswd -h {ssha} -c 'some_salt'.
```

it's better then plain md5.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/slappasswd.8.html

Result:

ssha512

```
slappasswd -h {ssha} -c '$6$%s' -s 123
```

{CRYPT}$6$s2mWoK1ZzwO0v02J$yi19QVOQB0ESrHwnCV.bl0RjwmwxWlNMl9z9FB0AqC9fL8SX2Q8Q2/k0Zj.l0qNtOacq6SWMdmfkDWQ4L1cqp.

```
dn: uid=test1,ou=People,dc=*,dc=*
uid: test1
cn: test1
sn: test1
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword: {CRYPT}$6$s2mWoK1ZzwO0v02J$yi19QVOQB0ESrHwnCV.bl0RjwmwxWlNMl9z9FB0AqC9fL8SX2Q8Q2/k0Zj.l0qNtOacq6SWMdmfkDWQ4L1cqp.
shadowLastChange: 16176
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 0
gidNumber: 0
homeDirectory: /home/test1
gecos: test1
```